# How find part of code linking to bad version of Qt?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5

I want to build some project (written in Qt4 but with subsequent changes) in Qt5. Building is successfull, but when I try run output file, it crashes. I think that it is cause by linking libQtCore.so.4 in one place (I saw it by "ldd OutputFile"). My problem is: how can I find that part of code, which refers to Qt4 module? The project is really big and has hundreds of files, debugger didn't help.

Comment: Try to make a clean build by invoking `make clean` command. Delete all makefiles and run `qmake` again. Build the project again.

Comment: I did it, QtCore from Qt4 is still linked.

Comment: Ok, I find very simple solution. I renamed libQtCore.so.4 library and I rebuild project to see in complilation log what file causes my problems. It was library from other project.

Comment: @trivelt It is very annoying to have multiple Qt versions on linux. I feel your pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just FYI; in order to quickly check if it was due to indirect dependency through shared libraries (as is commonly the case with a large project,) I would use `lddtree` from the `pax-utils` package (I use Ubuntu 12.04)

```
$ lddtree `which evince` 
evince => /usr/bin/evince (interpreter => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2)
    libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6
        libuuid.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1
            ld-linux.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-linux.so.2
    libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6
    libevdocument3.so.4 => /usr/lib/libevdocument3.so.4
        libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0
            libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
        libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
    libevview3.so.3 => /usr/lib/libevview3.so.3
        libgailutil-3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgailutil-3.so.0
        libgrip.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgrip.so.0
            libgeis.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgeis.so.1
                libgrail.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgrail.so.5
                    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
                    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
                libframe.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libframe.so.6
(snip; too long...)
```

The advantage over `ldd` is not so much if you have a single binary directly linked to many shared libraries, though

Comment: Thanks! I though about writing script, which will do `ldd` in each library linked from basic binary, but `lddtree` is answer to my needs.